# How to handle "Am I doing this right" questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I've noticed a lot of questions essentially asking this:

> "Here's some code, am I doing this the best/right/most efficient way?"

(for example: [How to prevent repeating code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937407/how-to-prevent-repeating-code))

I'm curious if these are on-topic, and if not, what's the proper action?

Comment: Your question does not accurately describe the example that you've posted

Comment: it doesn't? OP says in the question text: `Could this snippet of code be written more efficiently?`

Comment: the example is specifically asking about how to avoid writing duplicate code.  There's more to it than "here's my code is there a better way".

Comment: it's specific, but it still is looking for an opinion on how their code is written and soliciting ideas for either correctness or efficiency.

Comment: Let's be careful here. First we complain that users don't show any effort of solving the problem on their own. Then we say that if they *do* make an attempt at solving the problem, the question belongs on Code Review. Certainly it *could* be asked there, but **it is perfectly on topic for Stack Overflow**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course every question needs to be evaluated on its own merits, and not all questions of the same form will have the same problems, but there are generally two things to look out for when you see a question that is like that.

The most likely is that it's just going to be too broad.  This isn't *necessarily* the case, but usually there are just so many aspects of a code snippet that could each be evaluated independently that one can't expect a realistically scoped answer to completely cover all of them, nor do we want questions that collect a ton of answers each evaluating something different.

Another possibility is unclear, if it isn't clear what should be optimized, or by what metrics "best" is measured.  Sometimes it's clear in context, sometimes it's explicitly stated, and sometimes the question is just unclear for not having it.

Note that there is an entire site devoted to questions of this form: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  They do have standards (such as stating what metrics are to be evaluated) but there's a good chance that questions of this form that don't belong on SO can be altered in order to belong there.

Comment: so we should flag for moderators to move to code review?

Comment: @pennstatephil Usually not.  Generally a question will need to be re-written to be in line with the rules and guidelines of that site.  Unless you're familiar enough with that site to know that the given question meets all of those guidelines, you shouldn't flag it for migration.  The question author should be reading through the site's guidelines and re-writing the post with that intended audience.  The odds of the post needing no re-work are low, in my experiences.

Comment: Curious that this is getting downvotes, since it is essentially the correct answer.

Comment: @Servy so, a good idea would be to ask the OP to rewrite the question on Code Review (using the appropriate guidelines, of course), and then remove it from SO?

Comment: @pennstatephil Yes.  Assuming it doesn't actually meet SO's guidelines.  Many of these questions don't, but some can.

Answer (score -8):

Close for primarily opinion based or off-topic

point them toward https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: These questions are very often not opinion based, and they are not off topic.

Comment: Nor are they generally good candidates for Code Review.

Comment: Not all questions that are off-topic on Stack Overflow are on-topic on Code Review. In fact, their community has been [complaining about questions being incorrectly migrated](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/308/33330). See also: [What questions are suitable for migration to Code Review, and how does the process work?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1687/33330).