# What makes this question "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, needs-more-focus

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879421/most-efficient-way-to-execute-method-after-datetime-is-reached) question a couple of days ago, after coming across a problem for which I wasn't sure about the optimal solution. I did my best to explain the problem properly, provided example code, information about the context, and even my own working -but inefficient- solution.

Immediately I got two close votes, with the close reason being "Too Broad", and a third one this morning. I may be biased, but to me the question seems fine.

Could someone explain to me what makes this question too broad, so that I can avoid making such a mistake in future questions?

Comment: related: [Breaking down “too broad” and trying to understand it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258589/839601)

Comment: Your question has not been closed yet, so why the question here? Also why did you comment about the DV's in your question when it has 2 more UV's than DV's? Let them go.

Comment: On re-reading your question, it appears that it may be a poor fit for StackOverflow and perhaps a better fit for codereview stackexchange, since your code is in fact *working*, and you're interested not in fixing malbehavior but rather in improving its "efficiency".

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Its not the 4 rep I care about, but the fact that they presumably came from the same people who voted to close, meaning those people found my question to be completely inappropriate for SO. As for why I asked, I think the people who voted to close have some reason for doing so, and since they left no explanation, this is the only place I can find out what it is.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Perhaps it would fit better there, but then "Too broad" isn't the right close reason is it?

Comment: stybl, perhaps it's for the reason that I mentioned above. I don't know as I don't do C# and so don't have a dog in this fight, but again I'll recommend that you not be overly sensitive to DV's, else you'll be in for a lot of frustration on this site. As the song says, "Let it go".

Comment: Is it really necessary to involve performance in this question (performance questions make people very trigger-happy)? You can measure that yourself so asking about it as a worry before you do the measuring is premature, but you seem to be more worried about the design aspect of it. Surely it isn't necessary to fire off numerous timers, how to do it better.

Comment: IMO question does look fine and better than a lot that are posted on here regarding performance however out of _172 people_ that visited only 3 have decided to vote to close whilst 2 people downvoted. I'd say that's not bad going.

Comment: It's always best, when asking about performance, to be clear what you're evaluating. You ask for the "most efficient way", but don't define efficiency. Uses the least number of CPU cycles? The least amount of memory? See [How to handle “Am I doing this right” questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256646/215552) and [Are questions asking for “The best way” always primarily opinion-based?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348662/215552).